# Sorting elements by each names with XSL

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

I'd like to make a XSL stylesheet to transform xml in which elements are sorted by texts.

Source xml:

```
<package>
  <name>awesome-name</name>
  <version>1.0.6</version>
  <description>
    here is description
  </description>
  <maintainer email="foo@bar.com">Jon S.</maintainer>
  <maintainer email="aaa@bbb.com">George A.</maintainer>
  <license>BSD</license>
  <url>http://aaa.bbb.com/</url>
  <buildtool_depend>aaaaaaa</buildtool_depend>
  <!-- build depend -->
  <build_depend>aaaa</build_depend>
  <build_depend>dddd</build_depend>
  <build_depend>bbbb</build_depend>
  <build_depend>cccc</build_depend>
  <!-- run depend -->
  <run_depend>aaaa</run_depend>
  <run_depend>dddd</run_depend>
  <run_depend>cccc</run_depend>
  <run_depend>bbbb</run_depend>
  <export>
    <foo bar="aaa"></foo>
  </export>

  <!-- large
       footer
       comment -->
</package>
```

Expected output xml (`*_depend` are sorted in alphabetical order and other elements are just passed through):

```
<package>
  <name>awesome-name</name>
  <version>1.0.6</version>
  <description>
    here is description
  </description>
  <maintainer email="foo@bar.com">Jon S.</maintainer>
  <maintainer email="aaa@bbb.com">George A.</maintainer>
  <license>BSD</license>
  <url>http://aaa.bbb.com/</url>
  <buildtool_depend>aaaaaaa</buildtool_depend>
  <!-- build depend -->
  <build_depend>aaaa</build_depend>
  <build_depend>bbbb</build_depend>
  <build_depend>cccc</build_depend>
  <build_depend>dddd</build_depend>
  <!-- run depend -->
  <run_depend>aaaa</run_depend>
  <run_depend>bbbb</run_depend>
  <run_depend>cccc</run_depend>
  <run_depend>dddd</run_depend>
  <export>
    <foo bar="aaa"></foo>
  </export>

  <!-- large
       footer
       comment -->
</package>
```

but output was:

```
<package>
  <name>awesome-name</name>
  <version>1.0.6</version>
  <description>
    here is description
  </description>
  <maintainer email="foo@bar.com">Jon S.</maintainer>
  <maintainer email="aaa@bbb.com">George A.</maintainer>
  <license>BSD</license>
  <url>http://aaa.bbb.com/</url>
  <buildtool_depend>aaaaaaa</buildtool_depend>
  <build_depend>aaaa</build_depend>
  <build_depend>dddd</build_depend>
  <build_depend>bbbb</build_depend>
  <build_depend>cccc</build_depend>
  <run_depend>aaaa</run_depend>
  <run_depend>dddd</run_depend>
  <run_depend>cccc</run_depend>
  <run_depend>bbbb</run_depend>
  <export>
    <foo/>
  </export>
</package>
```

here, comment was deleted and inner element of export (`foo`) was not passed correctly.

The XSL stylesheet that I created is as following:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">                                     
  <xsl:preserve-space elements="description export"/>                                                               
  <xsl:template match="*">                                                                                          
    <xsl:element name="{name()}">                                                                                   
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />                                                                    
    </xsl:element>                                                                                                  
  </xsl:template>                                                                                                   

  <xsl:template match="@*|comment()">                                                                               
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />                                                                                      
  </xsl:template>                                                                                                   

  <xsl:template match="/package">                                                                                   
    <xsl:copy>                                                                                                      
      <xsl:copy-of select="*[self::name]" />                                                                        
      <xsl:copy-of select="*[self::version]" />                                                                     
      <xsl:copy-of select="*[self::description]" />                                                                 
      <xsl:copy-of select="*[self::maintainer]" />                                                                  
      <xsl:copy-of select="*[self::license]" />                                                                     
      <xsl:copy-of select="*[self::url]" />                                                                         
      <xsl:copy-of select="*[self::author]" />                                                                      
      <xsl:copy-of select="*[self::buildtool_depend]" />                                                            
      <xsl:copy-of select="*[self::buildtool_export_depend]" />                                                     
      <xsl:for-each select="build_depend">                                                                          
        <xsl:sort data-type="string" />                                                                             
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />                                                                                  
      </xsl:for-each>                                                                                               
      <xsl:for-each select="run_depend" >                                                                           
        <xsl:sort data-type="string" />                                                                             
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />                                                                                  
      </xsl:for-each>                                                                                               
      <xsl:for-each select="exec_depend" >                                                                          
        <xsl:sort data-type="string" />                                                                             
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />                                                                                  
      </xsl:for-each>                                                                                               
      <xsl:for-each select="test_depend">                                                                           
        <xsl:sort data-type="string" />                                                                             
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />                                                                                  
      </xsl:for-each>                                                                                               
      <xsl:for-each select="doc_depend">                                                                            
        <xsl:sort data-type="string" />                                                                             
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />                                                                                  
      </xsl:for-each>                                                                                               
      <xsl:for-each select="conflict">                                                                              
        <xsl:sort data-type="string" />                                                                             
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />                                                                                  
      </xsl:for-each>                                                                                               
      <xsl:for-each select="replace">                                                                               
        <xsl:sort data-type="string" />                                                                             
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />                                                                                  
      </xsl:for-each>                                                                                               
      <xsl:copy-of select="*[self::export]" />                                                                      
    </xsl:copy>                                                                                                     
  </xsl:template>                                                                                                   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What is wrong in my stylesheet, or any better solutions?

Comment: Note that `*[self::name]` is a convoluted way to write `name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way you could look at it:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/package">
    <xsl:copy>  
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(contains(name(), '_depend'))] 
                                   | buildtool_depend[1]
                                   | build_depend[1] 
                                   | run_depend[1]"/>       
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[contains(name(), '_depend')]">
    <xsl:for-each select="../*[name()=name(current())]" >                                                                           
        <xsl:sort/>                                                                             
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />                                                                                  
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, this is still rather awkward, having to list all possible element names. Consider instead a variation of [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html):

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="elem-by-name" match="*" use="name()" />

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/package">
    <xsl:copy>  
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()[not(contains(name(), '_depend'))] 
                                    | *[contains(name(), '_depend')][count(. | key('elem-by-name', name())[1]) = 1]"/>      
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="*[contains(name(), '_depend')]">
    <xsl:for-each select="key('elem-by-name', name())" >                                                                           
        <xsl:sort/>                                                                             
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />                                                                                  
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```